# Symfony FOSRestBundle error : Call to a member function get() on null. [Routing or Config error]

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle, symfony-3.3

My problem : I've a symfony 3 app. One Bundle for Rest Route (so my bundle is a rest API) and another Bundle who manage the front (Twig + Ajax).
I use fos_rest but it seem makes problems.

My config.yml:

```
fos_rest:
    routing_loader:
        include_format: false
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/rest', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: 'json' }
            - { path: '^/', stop: true }
```

My routing.yml :

```
front:
    resource: '@FrontBundle/Controller'
    type:     annotation

api:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller'
    type: rest
    prefix: '/rest'
```

and one basic route in my RestController :

```
/**
 * @Rest\View()
 * @Rest\Get("/participants")
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getParticipantsAction(Request $request)
{
    $participants = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager')
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:Participant')
        ->findAll();

    if (empty($participant)) {
        return new JsonResponse(['message' => 'There is no participants'], Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return $participants;
}
```

I test my route with postman and it send me an error `Error: Call to a member function get() on null`

Comment: 3.3 and FOSRestBundle has a problem with controllers being autowired incorrectly.  Basically the container is not being injected into the controller which causes $this->get() to fail. I think your best bet is to use S3.2 until the FOS bundles are updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with: `$participants = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')...`

or with `$participants = $this->getDoctrine()...`

Comment: It return `Call to a member function has() on null` with `$this->getDoctrine()` and `Call to a member function get() on null` with `$this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager')`

Comment: Please, paste some more info. File and the line of code where error happens would be useful :)

Comment: Is your controller defined as a service?

Comment: That was it. Appbundle by default is declared as a service in services.yml. I commented lines and everything work great.